# How to Monitor user idle in an applet inside a html using java script

Tags: javascript, java, html, applet

I have created an Applet and have ebbed it in html. I have java script that is able to handle user idleness and direct the user to login when idle for set timeout period. My problem is when I embed an applet within the same html with same javascript even if there are activities within the applet the java script still directs to the login page. My question is how can I make the html (java script) handle user inactivity within the applet. Here is my code.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

         <title>My Title</title>
         <script  type="text/javascript">
         function idleMonitor(){
         //code for idle is here
         }
         idleMonitor();

         </script>


    </head>
    <body>
 <div id="wrap">

           <applet id="center_div"  code="main.class" archive="MyApplet.jar" ></applet>

    </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have the applet send a heartbeat you can monitor

Comment: @mplungjan how can I do that do you have a sample code

Comment: No. Have a search for JavaScript applet